# Not able to get the value of element from xml using the xsl

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

**I have a XML document as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="student.xsl"?>
<StudentHeader>
  <student>
    <Roll>1</Roll>
    <Name>KUMAR</Name>
    <Sex>MALE</Sex>
 </student>
</StudentHeader>
```

`and I am using the following XSL sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Roll"/> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Name"/> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Sex"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name"> 
 <div style="color:purple">
<xsl:text> My Name is</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> 
 </div> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In Output I am getting Only text formated in green color like this: My Name is

MY Problem is: I am not getting the value of name attribute in xml.How can i get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're matching `<Name/>` elements that are inside other `<Name/>` elements. Query either the current context `.` or `text()` nodes instead:

```
<xsl:template match="Name"> 
 <div style="color:purple">
<xsl:text> My Name is</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
 </div> 
</xsl:template>
```